# Syntax error in UPDATE statement using access 2010 with c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am using MS access 2010 and try to connect it using C# windows application and use this code to update the data,

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE Admin SET UserName = @UN, Password = @Pass, ValidID = @VID WHERE ID = @ID";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", TBUserName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", TBPassword.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VID", CBvalidation.SelectedValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CBEmpName.SelectedValue);

ds.Tables.Add("Admin");
da.Fill(ds, "Admin");
```

in run time the error that appears is

> *"Syntax error in UPDATE statement"*

So please could u tell me where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

PASSWORD is a [reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) in Access JET/SQL.
You need to encapsulate it with square brackets

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE Admin SET UserName = @UN, " + 
                  "[Password] = @Pass, ValidID = @VID WHERE ID = @ID";
```

If it is possible, I suggest you to change the name of this field.
You will have always this problem for every future query on this table.

Answer (score 0):

`PASSWORD` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) on Access.

Use it with square brackets like `[PASSWORD]`

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE Admin SET UserName = @UN, [Password] = @Pass, ValidID = @VID WHERE ID = @ID";
```

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 com.CommandText = 
  "UPDATE Admin SET UserName = @UN, [Password] = @Pass, ValidID = @VID WHERE ID = @ID";
```

You can't use `Password` as it is reserved instead used `[Password]`